# How I can access the objects from Google APIs and Credentials page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm writing Deployment Manager scripts and would like to retrieve this info.

On the page console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials, there is a list of OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. I would like to access this by REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the list resource from REST Resource: v1.projects.brands on this link:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.brands

For more information check how to use the API to Programmatically creating OAuth clients for IAP:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients

Cheers.